# how to setup web server,application server,db server on multiple vm?

Tags: webserver, virtualization, virtual-machine, application-server, database-server

I would like to do my study practice.

To install the multiservers seperating on multiple vm -web server in first vm ,app server in second and db server in the last vm .then,I will create my own webpage to test about accessing data in db .Each of vm is based on VMware in my computer and just do it on localhost environment.not need to connect internet.

How can I do this or Where can I find any Tutorial .Plese give me some suggestion to finish my project ^^"

Thank u very muchh

Answer (score 0):

Just like what you do in physical machines. And IMHO, your question is too general and has nothing to do with virtual machines. I think what you are looking for is how to setup a web server and how to use a database. Why not check the sites such as nginx or apache and mysql or postgresql ?

Answer (score -1):

First of all you need to run all the machines and connected with each other.
By doing this you'll get IP addresses of those machines..

Now simply replace your IP addresses with localhost according to server

Note that every machine must have an appropriate server

Comment: Now I had run all machine and get their ip. but I don't know what program  to be using as webserver,app or db server. And how do I install them before config them to connect each other

Comment: if you want to build php application than you have to install wamp/xamp in both the machines....

Comment: then How to config them connecting each other.please advice me next